# org.openntf.domino API and what is equivalent to and com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument?

Tags: xpages

What is equivalent to com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument in org.openntf.domino API? I'm using this class when I send NotesXSPDocument to my java class from SSJS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no replacement for this class in the OpenNTF Domino API, which is designed to enclose and enhance the lotus.domino classes, not any of the com.ibm.xsp classes.

However, if you the org.openntf.domino.xsp plugin that comes bundled with the project and put it in "godmode" for your server or NSF, then any DominoDocument wrapper that you encounter will have an org.openntf.domino.Document instead of it instead of just a lotus.domino.Document. That way your Java class will get the right class automatically.

Alternatively, you can always manually wrap your lotus.domino.Document by using Factory.fromLotus([Document], org.openntf.domino.Document.class, null)  But I would generally recommend using the plugin. It's much simpler and keeps you from having to worry about the implementation of the openntf version.